# How to Cast a local image to Chromecast from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I want to cast device local photo to Chromecast but only loading screen is displayed on Chromecast and no photo is showed.

I successfully cast the video using this method .Please suggest me how can I show local photo to cromecast.

**This is my code for cast photo to Chromecast**

```
func sendPhotoFile() {
  let port = String(HttpServerManager.shared.getServerURL())
  let photoHttpUrl = port + "search.png"

  let metadata = GCKMediaMetadata(metadataType: .photo)
     metadata.setString("For Bigger Escape", forKey: kGCKMetadataKeyTitle)
     metadata.addImage(GCKImage(url: URL(string: photoHttpUrl)!, width: kThumbnailWidth, height: kThumbnailHeight))

  let mediaInfo: GCKMediaInformation = GCKMediaInformation(contentID: photoHttpUrl, streamType: .none, contentType: kTypePhoto, metadata: metadata, adBreaks: nil, adBreakClips: nil, streamDuration: 0, mediaTracks: nil, textTrackStyle: nil, customData: nil)

  let session = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
  if (session != nil) {
    session?.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(mediaInfo)
  }
}
```

I am looking for an example of casting an image to a chrome cast from a url. There doesn't seem to be an image cast example in the google cast sample repositories but i feel this must have been done before.

I have little experience with the chrome cast sdk developer console as well as the development of the apps themselves so any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution.how to cast UiImage local image to URL in IOS